# Having problems with resetting Buffered Reader

Tags: java, file, io, bufferedreader, ioexception

Here is my code:

```
int lines = 0;
  br.mark(0);
  while (br.readLine() != null) lines++;
  System.out.print(lines);
  br.reset();
```

I am trying to figure out the number of lines in the input file and then reset it back to the top so I don't get errors later on in the code. I thought it was possible to use the mark and reset methods. Also, my file is relatively small, as from other answers I learned it could be a problem if it was too big. Is my usage of these incorrect? Here is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Mark invalid
    at java.io.BufferedReader.reset(BufferedReader.java:512)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Comment: I _think_ your use of `mark(0)` is the problem—check out [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#mark(int)). In other words, if I understand the docs correctly, as soon as you read _anything_ the mark is invalidated because you passed `0` as an argument.

Comment: Oh, so how would I determine the number of characters that it can read while still preserving the mark?

Comment: I suppose you could try `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and just forget about it, though depending on how the feature is implemented this could cause problems. But anyway, why are you using a `BufferedReader` like this? It seems like you're trying to count the lines, rewind, and then process the text. If that's correct then consider just reading all the text into a `List<String>` where each element is a line (letting you query `size()` for the line count) and throwing away the `BufferedReader`. Both approaches will cause the entire text to be read into memory anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   String fileName="put file path here";
   int lines= (int) Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName)).count();
```

or

```
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName))) {

            //br returns as stream and convert it into a List
            lines = (int) br.lines().count()

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SpringApplication.run(QuicksilverApplication.class, args);
    }
```

Comment: I'm kind of new to java and when I try and use your first method, I get an error saying cannot find symbol for variable paths and file. Am I supposed to replace it with something or import something?

Comment: Yes you need to set the fileName variable with the file path

Comment: What would be the path for a file in my current working directory?

Comment: try something like this `./filename` or you can use the full path? can you share how did structure your project? how do you run it?